# Insert, display, min and max in array list in C#

Tags: c#

I'm new in C#. I have this program and I need to add the function for insert, function min, function max, and function display.

```
namespace unSortedArrayAssignment
{
    class unSortedArray
    {
        public int size;
        public int[] array;
        //Constructor for an empty unsorted array
        public unSortedArray(int MAX_SIZE)
        {
            array = new int[MAX_SIZE]; //Create a C# array of size MAX_SIZE
            size = 0; // Set size of unSortedArray to 0
        }
        //Append assuming array is not full
        public void Append(int value)
        {
            array[size] = value;
            size++;
        }
        //Remove the last item
        public void Remove()
        {
            if (size != 0)
                size--;
        }
        //Search for an item
        public int Search(int value)
        {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
            {
                if (array[counter] == value)
                    return counter;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        //Delete an item
        public void Delete(int value)
        {
            int index = Search(value);
            if (index != 0)
            {
                for (int counter = index; counter < size; counter++)
                    array[counter] = array[counter + 1];
                size--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no i need to add this methods to this program thank you

Comment: @benjibenji if you paste your code to VS before posting here, It can format your code as above....

Comment: @benjibenji do realize we shouldn't be a code-writing service, although some users think it is OK to do your work.

Comment: A "Display" method would depend on how you wanted to display the data and also the type of application that you are using.

Answer (score -2):

```
class unSortedArray
{
    public int size;
    public int[] array;

    public unSortedArray()
    {
       array = new int[int size here];
    }

    public int Min()
    {
       return array.Min();
    }

    public int Max()
    {
       return array.Max();
    }

    public void Insert(int value)
    {
        Array.Resize<int>(ref array, array.Count() + 1);
        array[array.Count() - 1] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: i need this code  public void Display()

{


}


public int Max()

{
}

public int Min()

{
} public void Insert(int value)

{



}

Comment: Can you explain where those Min, Max and Count methods come from? They are not mentioned as methods available on the Array type. What kind of magic is that?

Comment: @rene they are `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods defined in `System.Linq`